# Passing parameters in Dart from one anonymous function to another using the variable name

Tags: dart, parameters, anonymous-function

I'm reposting the (very slightly modified) code of a reader question from [here](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/chapter-5-passing-functions-to-functions-why-doesnt-this-work/169740).

```dart
void main() {
  double taxRate = .0825;
  double costOfProduct = 9.99;

  Function totalCostOfProduct =
      ({required double taxRate, required double costOfProduct}) {
    return (costOfProduct * taxRate) + costOfProduct;
  };

  print(totalCostOfProduct(taxRate: taxRate, costOfProduct: costOfProduct));

  String tellMeThePrice({required Function totalCostOfProduct}) {
    return "THE PRICE IS ${totalCostOfProduct}";
  }

  print(
    tellMeThePrice(
      totalCostOfProduct: totalCostOfProduct(
        taxRate: taxRate,
        totalCostOfProduct: costOfProduct,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Running this in DartPad gives the following error:

```
TypeError: totalCostOfProduct.call$2$taxRate$totalCostOfProduct is not a function
Error: TypeError: totalCostOfProduct.call$2$taxRate$totalCostOfProduct is not a function
```

There are a few things going on here I think:

- Printing `totalCostOfProduct` in `tellMeThePrice` tries to print the function itself without printing the value returned by the function.
- When `tellMeThePrice` is actually called, the code passes in the result of the function (a double) rather than the function itself. (Hence, the type error.)

In an attempt to solve these problems I tried the following modifications:

```dart
  String tellMeThePrice({required Function totalCostOfProduct}) {
    final result = totalCostOfProduct.call();
    return "THE PRICE IS $result";
  }

  print(
    tellMeThePrice(
      totalCostOfProduct: (taxRate, costOfProduct) => totalCostOfProduct(
        taxRate: taxRate,
        totalCostOfProduct: costOfProduct,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

This still returns an error:

```
TypeError: totalCostOfProduct.call$0 is not a function
Error: TypeError: totalCostOfProduct.call$0 is not a function
```

This is a contrived example by the reader to use two functions. However, it also stumped me. How do I pass the parameters on to the second function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that totalCostOfProduct is returning double data type and you are taking totalCostOfProduct as a function in the tellMeThePrice function.
So it will return a double data type instead of a function.

just change `String tellMeThePrice({required Function totalCostOfProduct})` to  `String tellMeThePrice({required double totalCostOfProduct})`
because it'e returning double data type.

```
void main() {
  double taxRate = .0825;
  double costOfProduct = 9.99;

  Function totalCostOfProduct =
      ({required double taxRate, required double costOfProduct}) {
    return (costOfProduct * taxRate) + costOfProduct;
  };

  print(totalCostOfProduct(taxRate: taxRate, costOfProduct: costOfProduct));

  String tellMeThePrice({required double totalCostOfProduct}) {
    return "THE PRICE IS ${totalCostOfProduct}";
  }

  print(
    tellMeThePrice(
      totalCostOfProduct: totalCostOfProduct(
        taxRate: taxRate,
        costOfProduct: costOfProduct,
      ),
    ).toString()
  );     // THE PRICE IS 10.814175
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. This is a better way to achieve the desired result. However, as contrived as the original example is, I'm still trying to understand how to pass parameters from one anonymous function to another. This is more of a theoretical question rather than solving a practical problem.